# Can we parametrize a smooth curve by arc length?

Tags: analysis

Let $c:I=[0,a]\rightarrow R^n$ be a smooth curve such that $J=\{t\in I | c'(t)=0 \}$ has empty interior. Can we parametrize $c$ by the arc length, $c=c(s),\  c: I_1=[0,b]\rightarrow R^n$ so that $|c'(s)|=1$ for all $s\in I_1$?

Comment: You might be interested in intrinsic coordinates - you need more than arc length, but that can be part of the picture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_equation

Comment: In many cases curves can be expressed in terms of a *natural equation*, which is typically a relation between curvature (or radius of curvature), tangent angle, and arc length, $\kappa (\rho), ~\theta,~s$ that is independent of any coordinate system.